# Why is while part of another function called when I did not call the function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

board = ["-", "-", "-",
"-", "-", "-",
"-", "-", "-"]

```
def input_moveX(): #tictactoe move X
    position = (input("Place your mark X:")) #user input
    position = int(position) - 1
    board[position] = "X"
    display_boardX()

def display_boardX():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + " | ")
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + " | ")
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + " | ")
    winner()
    print('Catch')


def input_moveY():
    position = (input("Place your mark O:"))
    position = int(position) - 1
    board[position] = "O"
    display_boardY()


def display_boardY():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + " | ")
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + " | ")
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + " | ")
    while board[0] or board[1] or board[2] or board[3] or board[4] or board[5] or board[6] or board[7] or board[8] != "-":
        input_moveX() #input X again



def winner():
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == "X" or board[3] == board[4] == board[5] == "X" or board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == "X":
        print('X is the winner!!!')
    else:
        while board[0] or board[1] or board[2] or board[3] or board[4] or board[5] or board[6] or board[7] or board[8] != "-":
            input_moveY()
```

#call fxn to start the game
input_moveX()

#After printing Catch it goes directly to while condition

Comment: Which while loop are you talking about? To avoid ambiguity, please [edit] your question to show the exact command you're running, and the exact output it gives.

Comment: The statements in the ```while``` are always true.

Comment: Also, this is creating a long chain of unfinished calls.

Answer (score 0):

Board is initially `["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]`.

Begin program at `input_moveX()`, which asks for user input. Lets say user chooses position `1`.

Board becomes `["X", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]`

`display_boardX()` is called, which prints the board and then calls the `winner()` function. The first `if` condition fails, since positions 0, 1 & 2 do not all equal 'X'. The same is true for positions 3, 4 & 5, as well as 6, 7 & 8. So the `else` is entered, which enters the `while` loop.

From what I can see, entering the `while` loop is entirely expected.

Comment: when I debugged, right before it went to while, the line that executed was Catch. As a beginner, I'm not sure how it got directed to while (skipping print board) when I did not point it to flow to fxn display_board right after execute of Catch..

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and after **while** was changed to **if**, I realized that the issue of executing the other defiintions again is because I missed the concept of a function within a function - the 2nd fxn should go "home" to it's mother function which had a succeeding command causing that command to execute the same number of times the 2nd fxn was triggered and went "home". :)

Thank you for the guidance.